# SunCertPathBuilderException with SHA-2 signed certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl

I recently got a new certificate for a web site and had it generated with the SHA-2 signature algorithm as recommended. Everything looked fine until I tried to make a secure connection to that web site in Java (java.net.URLConnection), which resulted in a

```
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

which commonly happens with self-signed certificates. Only this was not a self-signed certificate, and HTTPS requests worked fine from a browser.

The problem went away when I had the certificate re-keyed with the SHA-1 signature algorithm.

Why can I not use a SHA-2 signed certificate with a recent JDK (1.7.0_45)?
Is there anything I can do make the JDK accept a SHA-2 signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use sha-2 certs quite a bit in java, so I'm pretty sure it's not sha-2 itself that is the issue, but the CA from which it was issued from.

It's likely that since it was a sha-2 cert, it was issued from a newer sha-2 CA which was registered in the web browser but **not** in Java's default truststore (cacerts file).  The sha-1 cert probably worked since it was issued from an older CA that **was** present in the truststore.

You will need to export the CA cert which issued the sha-2 web site cert and import it into your java truststore.  If you put the url into the web browser you should be able to click the lock icon and see the whole chain.  The CA cert is the one at the top.

1. Get the CA cert in base64 format as ca.cer (I can post the exact steps if you need them).  Note that keytool requires the cert to be in base64 format or it will reject it.
2. Run this command (replace JAVA_HOME with your JDK path):
   **JAVA_HOME\bin\keytool -keystore JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts -import -file ca.cer -alias newca**
3. You will be prompted for a password, type "changeit" without the quotes
4. You will be asked "Trust this certificate? [no]"  type "yes"

Now java.net.URLConnection should work.  We run into this issue quite a bit, would be nice if Oracle would publish updates for the cacerts file.

Comment: Thanks, that may well be the problem. Unfortunately I cannot update the trust stores of all the people who are using my software to access my server securely.

Comment: Ah, so this is a web service that is accessed by other java clients?